# Pyqt 50+ Checkboxes --- How to go about this

Tags: function, checkbox, ide, pyqt

If a checkbox is checked then I would like to append a value to a list, and remove if unchecked.

The documentation is a little confusing --- there is clicked() toggled() toggle() stateChange() and a bunch of others. All these should work for adding the value to the list, but how would I remove it when somebody unchecks rather than addin it again.

This list is passed into another function.

I am just having trouble figuring out the best way to do this, there are around 50 checkboxes and an all checkbox

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WG94.png)
Could I do this with just one function.... maybe use a dictionary with the values as the strings to be passed into the list and put the keys in stateChange() , or do I need to write the entire process out for every single checkbox?

I guess this is just weird because I am used to debugging in canopy, but canopy doesn't work with PyQt, so now I'm on sublime.

Thanks

Comment: Some more information about what you are trying to achieve may be required, but why not check the state of all checkboxes before you call the function, rather than trying to manage a list?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the `clicked()` signal to a function that contains an `if`-statement that looks if the checkbox is checked or not.

Example:

```
self.checkbox.clicked.connect(checkbox_state_fu)

def checkbox_state_fu(self):
    if self.checkbox.checkState() != 0:
    # checkState() is only False for 0.
        state = True  
    else:
        state = False
```

Inside the `if`-statement you can add/remove your item from the list as you wish.